# What is the difference between sample() and rsample()?

Tags: python, random, pytorch

When I sample from a distribution in PyTorch, both `sample` and `rsample` appear to give similar results:

```
import torch, seaborn as sns

x = torch.distributions.Normal(torch.tensor([0.0]), torch.tensor([1.0]))
```

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |
| `sns.distplot(x.sample((100000,)))` | `sns.distplot(x.rsample((100000,)))` |

When should I use `sample()`, and when should I use `rsample()`?

Answer (score 23):

`sample()`: random sampling from the probability distribution. So, we **cannot** backpropagate, because it is random! (the computation graph is **cut off**).

See the source code of `sample` in `torch.distributions.normal.Normal`:

```
def sample(self, sample_shape=torch.Size()):
    shape = self._extended_shape(sample_shape)
    with torch.no_grad():
        return torch.normal(self.loc.expand(shape), self.scale.expand(shape))
```

`torch.normal` returns a tensor of *random* numbers. Also, `torch.no_grad()` context prevents the computation graph from growing any further.

You see, we cannot backprop. The returned tensor of `sample()` contains just some numbers, not the whole computational graph.

---

### So, what is `rsample()`?

By using `rsample`, we **can** backpropagate, because it **keeps the computation graph** alive.

How? By putting the randomness aside in a separate parameter. This is called the "reparameterization trick".

***r**sample: sampling using **r**eparameterization trick.*

There is `eps` in the source code:

```
def rsample(self, sample_shape=torch.Size()):
    shape = self._extended_shape(sample_shape)
    eps = _standard_normal(shape, dtype=self.loc.dtype, device=self.loc.device)
    return self.loc + eps * self.scale

    # `self.loc` is the mean and `self.scale` is the standard deviation.
```

`eps` is the separate parameter responsible for the randomness of the sampling.

Look at the return:  mean + `eps` * standard deviation

`eps` does **not** depend on the parameters you want to differentiate with respect to.

So, now you can freely backpropagate(=differentiate) because `eps` does not change when the parameters change.

(If we change the parameters, the distribution of the reparameterized samples *does* change because `self.loc` and `self.scale` change, but the distribution of the `eps` does *not* change.)

Note that the randomness of the sampling comes from the random sampling of the `eps`. There is *no* randomness in the computation graph itself. Once `eps` is chosen, it is fixed. (the distribution of the elements of the `eps` is fixed, after they are sampled.)

For example, in an implementation of the SAC(Soft Actor-Critic) algorithm in reinforcement learning, `eps` may consist of elements corresponding to a single minibatch of actions (and one action may consist of many elements).

Comment: Well, that explains why my first attempt at porting a VAE to use `torch.distributions` didn't work! The other reason is I used Normal rather than IndependentNormal (or independent(Normal).

Answer (score 21):

Using `rsample` allows for [pathwise derivatives](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html#pathwise-derivative):

> The other way to implement these stochastic/policy gradients would be to use the reparameterization trick from the `rsample()` method, where the parameterized random variable can be constructed via a parameterized deterministic function of a parameter-free random variable. The reparameterized sample therefore becomes differentiable.

Comment: Could you give an example that does not involve reinforcement learning?

Comment: Variational autoencoders use the reparameterization trick to allow backpropagation through the mean and standard deviation layers.